# Mysql Cluster with django

Tags: mysql, django

I would like to use Mysql Cluster 7.2 with django.
For High Avaibility, One should be able to specify into django : 2 SQL servers from the Mysql cluster with a failover behaviour : if one connection fails, django must use the second one.

How to configure that ?

Answer (score 1):

Failover feature is not in Django per se.

I am also looking for this for future improvements of a project I am involved in. I found the following module as one of the best chances to solve this problem:

https://github.com/brianjaystanley/django-failover

In resume: a monitor checks for database availability and if database is down or slow changes database connection settings on the fly. The module looks great cause takes care of cache and celery too.

Anyway, it depends of your architecture behind the scenes.